# Can I create a dropdown menu from the titles in blue without JS?

Tags: html, css, confluence

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the 2 titles ("Core Processes" and "LDO Collaborative") have a dropdown and have boxes/cards below each appear and disappear. Hence, web navigation is not that complicated and faster. But after doing some research most of the dropdowns I've found JS is needed.[image: current navigation page]
(The image shows how my page is at the moment but would like to hide those cards within each title)

Comment: Yes, any dynamic actions requires JS. CSS is only for representation and HTML is just Markup Language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use focus but note that it only works with buttons and the element has to come after the button. you can select with `adjacent sibling selector (+)` or `general sibling selector (~)`

```css
p{
width:90vw;
height:80vh;
background-color:teal;
transition:height 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
button:focus + p{
height:0vh;
}
```

```html
<button>Tag1</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: ok thanks for that, do you know a way to use JS on Confluence server? That is the main reason I'm trying to avoid anything that has JS

Comment: you can also try `:target` selector https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target_tab

Comment: i also updated the answer with a smoother transition